# The filter does not clear the previously selected countries. When i try to make a new selection the previous does not erase and list the old one too

Tags: html, filter, insert, delete-row, auto-update

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Playground!</title>
    <!-- Setup for mobile device screen physical width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select
        id="originCountry"
        onchange="onCountrySelect('origin', this.value)"
      >
        <option>Origin Country</option>
      </select>
      <select
        id="departureCountry"
        onchange="onCountrySelect('destination', this.value)"
        style="margin-left: 60px"
      >
        <option>Destination Country</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="originCity">
        <option>Departure City</option>
      </select>
      <select id="destinationCity" style="margin-left: 60px">
        <option>Arrival City</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>
      const countries = ["US", "RO"];
      const cities = [
        { name: "Las Vegas", country: "US" },
        { name: "Boston", country: "US" },
        { name: "New York", country: "US" },
        { name: "Cluj", country: "RO" },
        { name: "Timisoara", country: "RO" },
        { name: "Arad", country: "RO" },
      ];
      function appendOptionsToSelect(element, list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          var opt = list[i];
          var el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = opt;
          el.value = opt;
          element.appendChild(el);
        }
      }
      // create select for Origin Country & populate options
      const originCountryElm = document.getElementById("originCountry");
      appendOptionsToSelect(originCountryElm, countries);
      // create select for Destination Country & populate options
      const destinationCountryElm = document.getElementById("departureCountry");
      appendOptionsToSelect(destinationCountryElm, countries);
      // create select for Origin/Destination Cities
      const originCitiesElm = document.getElementById("originCity");
      const destinationCitiesElm = document.getElementById("destinationCity");
      function onCountrySelect(countryType, newValue) {
        console.log(
          "Selected country is of type",
          countryType,
          "with name: ",
          newValue
        );
        // get only cities from that country
        const matchingCities = cities
          .filter((item) => item.country === newValue)
          .map((item) => item.name);
```

*todo - remove existing options before assiging new ones. The filter does not clear the previously selected countries. When i try to make a new selection the previous does not erase and list the old one too and when i try to make a new select it goes indefinitly and will list the same selection again and again*

```
        if (countryType === "origin") {

          appendOptionsToSelect(originCitiesElm, matchingCities);
        } else {
          appendOptionsToSelect(destinationCitiesElm, matchingCities);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just needed to clear out the previous options before appending the new options.

I've added a new function to clear out previous options and it needs to be called before appending the new options.

```js
function clearOptions(selectElement) {
   const len = selectElement.options.length - 1;
   for(let i = len; i >= 1; i--) {
      selectElement.remove(i);
   }
}

function onCountrySelect(countryType, newValue) {
  console.log(
    "Selected country is of type",
    countryType,
    "with name: ",
    newValue
  );
  // get only cities from that country
  const matchingCities = cities
    .filter((item) => item.country === newValue)
    .map((item) => item.name);

  if (countryType === "origin") {
    clearOptions(originCitiesElm);
    appendOptionsToSelect(originCitiesElm, matchingCities);
  } else {
    clearOptions(destinationCitiesElm);
    appendOptionsToSelect(destinationCitiesElm, matchingCities);
  }
}
```